# How can I find out what IRC Daemon a certain server is running?

Tags: irc, daemon

To get an overview on IRC, I wanted to find out what kind of IRC server software/daemon (like unrealircd) runs on a certain server.

Is there a possibility to get this information?

Comment: Often (but not always) when you connect to an irc server, you are given the server daemon package name and version as part of the intro dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most clients you can type '/quote version' or just '/version' and it will query the server, which by default on most IRCds will respond with the info, like:

```
-> Odd server stuff: "351 InspIRCd-1.2 hub.yourdomain.com :FreeBSD hub.yourdomain.com 6
.2-RELEASE (InspIRCd-1.2.1) [FLAGS=0,kqueue,196]" (hub.yourdomain.com)
005 WALLCHOPS WALLVOICES MODES=19 CHANTYPES=# PREFIX=(ohv)@%+ MAP
MAXCHANNELS=20 MAXBANS=60 VBANLIST NICKLEN=31 CASEMAPPING=rfc1459
STATUSMSG=@%+ CHARSET=ascii : are supported by this server
005 TOPICLEN=307 KICKLEN=255 MAXTARGETS=19 AWAYLEN=200 CHANMODES=b,k,l,
BMNRcimnprstz FNC NETWORK=hubns MAXPARA=32 ELIST=MU EXTBAN=,MRNcB SAFELIST
SECURELIST SSL=204.14.231.5:6697 :are supported by this server 
005 STARTTLS USERIP : are supported by this server
```

Answer (score 1):

this command tells you something about the server.

```
C:\nmap>nmap -P0 -sV -p6667 irc.undernet.org

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-09-03 18:07 GMT Daylight Time
Nmap scan report for irc.undernet.org (208.83.20.130)
Host is up (0.14s latency).
Other addresses for irc.undernet.org (not scanned): 64.18.128.86 66.198.80.67 66
.252.29.2 70.33.251.254 77.247.181.225 94.125.182.255 95.141.29.22 130.237.188.2
16 194.109.20.90
rDNS record for 208.83.20.130: Tampa.FL.US.Undernet.org
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
6667/tcp open  irc     ircu ircd

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.
org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.55 seconds

C:\nmap>
```